# Persistent name for USB HID (LED) gadget

Tags: linux, usb-device, hid

I have a USB LED gadget that shows up as a USB HID device. When I plug it in to my server it shows up as `/sys/class/leds/delcom2:{red,green,blue}` and I can operate it by manipulating the files that show up there.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr  7 13:22 /sys/class/leds/delcom2:blue -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/0003:0FC5:B080.0007/leds/delcom2:blue
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr  7 13:22 /sys/class/leds/delcom2:green -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/0003:0FC5:B080.0007/leds/delcom2:green
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr  7 13:22 /sys/class/leds/delcom2:red -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/0003:0FC5:B080.0007/leds/delcom2:red
```

My problem is that the name `delcom2` changes from machine to machine. On another computer it is named `delcom5`, and I worry that it will get yet another name if I plug it into a USB hub or similar. I would like some kind of *persistent naming* for this gadget so that I can manipulate it reliably from scripts.

I have tried writing an udev rule, but failed. Most of the information I find about renaming talks about `SYMLINK+="..."` but that does not seem to work. It *does* give me a symlink to the raw USB device:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr  7 13:45 /dev/delcom -> bus/usb/003/003
```

I also tried with the `NAME="..."` method, but that also fails:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fc5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b080", NAME="delcom"
```

The last line of the systemd journal log shows why it is failing: **kernel device nodes cannot be renamed**

```
usb 5-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080
usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 5-1: Product: USB IO Controller 
usb 5-1: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.
hid-led 0003:0FC5:B080.0008: hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Delcom Products Inc. USB IO Controller ] on usb-0000:00:1a.2-1/input0
hid-led 0003:0FC5:B080.0008: Delcom Visual Signal Indicator G2 initialized
systemd-udevd[17574]: NAME="delcom" ignored, kernel device nodes cannot be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-led.rules:1
```

#### Question

How can I create a persistent name for a USB HID LED device in linux?